# Delete file ending with .csv in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to write a script that remove files ending .csv from an input folder. I try to write this:

```
# the direction path of the folder
dirPath="$1"
# remove the files ending .csv
find $dirPath -type f -name "*.csv" | while read filename; do
rm "$filename"
     done
```

But it's not working, how can we fix it?

Comment: What is not working, what did you expect to happen or see that did not? Is there any error?

Comment: There is no error but it's not deleted the files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why make it so complicated, while `find` has a `-delete` switch?

```
find $dirPath -type f -name "*.csv" -delete
```

Comment: Minor note: While it seems to be rather portable, `-delete` is not POSIX. Related comparison with `-exec rm`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167823/finds-exec-rm-vs-delete

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
find /path/to/directory -type f -name "*.csv" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do `find $dirPath -name \*.csv -exec rm -f {}`

exec will let you to execute rm on each file found.

Refer [Here](https://baeldung.com/linux/find-exec-command)